# Uploaded image on wordpress website not displayed on mobile device

Tags: wordpress, mobile-website

I am newbie on Wordpress. I have just started blogs - 
[finkomist.info](http://finkomist.info/)
I have developed this as responsive site.
If you notice the only post I have, it has image. This is seen on computer, but on mobile device this image is disappeared.

I have used theme - simplified blog.

Could someone help me understand the changes in the settings if images needs to be Response sensitive ?

Comment: can you provide the page link ?

Comment: you developed the site on localhost and now all your images refers to it... You should change all images reference on the db or upload and attach the images to the post again.

Comment: Obviously you see the images on your computer because you are actually on localhost, when you try to open the site from an external device you get a 404 error

Comment: Yes, as mentioned by DaFois, image was referring to localhost i.e. my trial & error desktop site.
I have removed it from media & uploaded the same image. I have changed the link referring to image to what [finkomist.info][1] should refer to.


  [1]: http://finkomist.info

DaFois, you've mentioned to change the all image reference in the DB. I could not follow that clearly. Though my problem seem to be solved, Could you please elaborate on this part ?

Answer (score 0):

i cannot see any images on your website even in computer. try re-uploading all the images & make sure to insert them into the post using editor.